# How to compare JSON-like text in MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, json

DBMS: MySQL 5.6

I have a table `tbl` of which column `json` stores JSON-like text, the type of column is `text`. The column `json` looks like

```
{"id": "123", "name": "foo", "age": "20"}
```

---

I tried to select rows with the condition `json.id = '123'`. The query `select * from tbl where json like '%"id": "123"%'` failed.

I found MySQL 5.6 not supporting Json functions. So how to use Json in the `WHERE` clause?

---

### Append

The schema that storing a JSON in a single column is definitely not so reasonable. But I cannot modify the schema since the business has run for a while. The version of MySQL is out of same concern. So I think a workaround is needed.

Comment: You don't - you normalize your data (with the columns `id`, `name`, `age`) or at least normalize what you're going to SELECT your data by. The best you can hope for is using regex to select your data and/or searching by acting like the entire thing is a string.

Comment: If it's possible use PostgreSQL. It has good [JSON support](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html)

Comment: @LukaszWiktor If that was possible, surely he'd just use MySQL 5.7 [considering it has JSON support as well](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) (from 5.7.8)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Good to know that MySQL can also handle JSON. Thanks!

Comment: @h2ooooooo sound great when MySQL 5.7 support json query

Comment: @h2ooooooo Thank you for your advice. But the business has run for months thus I cannot modify the schema of table nor the MySQL version. I therefore have to find a workaround.

Comment: @Zelong I feel your pain - been there myself. Would it be possible for you to create a new adjacent table with the correct normalized data that you can use for selecting this particular bit of data? (eg. `relational_id`, `json_id`) and simply JOIN using that table? Perhaps have a cron job that often updates this table? It's a hacky solution, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

use `LOCATE`

```
Select * from tbl where 
LOCATE('"id": "123"','{"id": "123", "name": "foo", "age": "20"}') >0
```

Comment: LOCATE like String.indexOf() function in some language

Answer (score 0):

Try this, common_schema is used for json parsing,

```
SELECT json 
    FROM tbl
    WHERE common_schema.extract_json_value(json ,'id')
    LIKE "123%"
```

Answer (score -1):

```
select * from tbl where json like '%\"id\": \"123\"%'
```

try this. I have escaped " character.

Comment: good idea but not optimize for query speed when table have much row like that (json string)